# How to get Token in android with java to make notifications sent successfully

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, token

I try about week to send notification between devices using Firebase Functions now i found delay or the notification don't received to another device so after many trys i found solution is iam generate wrong token so i seek now the right way to generate tokens

FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() 
its return wrong token

extends FirebaseMessagingService 
cant know how it works and after many tries it still return null

Comment: what makes you think, the token you recieve from the firebase instance is wrong?

Comment: because i made try and i put the token in database and when i take this token copy the fcm is working

Comment: So if you put the token you generate with `GetToken`into a database and then use it in the fcm console where it works? Seems not the token is wrong but the way you use it in your app when sending